# jquery .removeClass() if NOT .next()

Tags: jquery

How would I go about remove the class from all elements except the next one?

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Trigger</a></li>
  <li class="next"><a href="#">Trigger</a></li>
  <li class="next"><a href="#">Trigger</a></li>
  <li class="next"><a href="#">Trigger</a></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on Trigger link `a` removes all the `"next"` classes from the `li` elements except the one directly below

I'm not worried about the whole set of code to achieve this. I've written everything that I need apart from this one thing of removing the class except on the next li?!

**UPDATE: *SOLVED***

Seems I overlooked a simple solution which works well:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().not().next().removeClass('next');
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method to get all consecutive siblings after the current element. Then, reduce the set using [`.slice(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(1).removeClass('next');
});
```

The previous method only removes `next` from later items. If you want to affect **all** siblings, the following can be used:

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.siblings().not($parent.next()).removeClass('next');
});
```

Another option: Remove the `next` class from all elements, then add it to the next element.

Comment: is this a better/technically more correct way than the solution I posted? Mine seems to work too but looks ver simple.

Comment: I posted it as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Just realised it's very simple!

```
$(this).parent().siblings().not().next().removeClass('next');
```

Comment: `.not()` is not even necessary. The negating effect of [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) does not chain. Your code somehow *seems* to work, but it doesn't: The first sibling is never affected: http://jsfiddle.net/fmGPk/2/

Comment: Even though you've found a solution that seems to work, it's better to stick to standards and best practices. This code may eventually stop working at one point in the future (not that this is likely, but it's possible, of course). @RobW's method is an excellent way of doing it.

Comment: @Purmou – thanks for the clarification. I didn't think it was correct, was amazed it worked. I'll revert to Robs solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.next').not($(this).next()).removeClass('next');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var $ul = $('ul').on('click', 'a', function () {

    // get the next element
    var n = $(this).next('a');

    // get everything else except this
    $ul.find('a').not(this).removeClass('next');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the nextAll for the next li element , and your li is a parent of the links

```
$("a").click( function() {
   $(this).parent().next().nextAll().removeClass();  
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7KaS/