# jQuery not next and not before

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way of jQuery selecting all sibling elements except both previous and next? I have looked into [jquery .removeClass() if NOT .next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701403/jquery-removeclass-if-not-next) but can't seem to find a way of doing BOTH. Also, Google didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: "all" what? Siblings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** Use [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

```
var index = $(this).index();
var $elements = $(this).siblings().filter(function(){
   var thisindex = $(this).index();
   return  thisindex < index-1 || thisindex > index+1;
});
```

You might also use a string selector with [lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) but it would mean concatenating the index to build a selector just for jQuery to parse if afterwards and do the same loop.

**Solution 2 :** use [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) :

```
var index = $(this).index();
var $elements =$(this).siblings();
$elements = $elements.slice(0, index-1).add($elements.slice(index+1));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/egovuw/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var item = $('selector');
var elements = item.siblings().not(item.prev()).not(item.next());
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/s9aJp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var $this = $(this)
, $rest = $this.parent().children().not($this.prev()).not($this.next()).not($this);
```

If you want the current element also included in the result, just remove the last not call.

```
var $this = $(this)
, $rest = $this.parent().children().not($this.prev()).not($this.next());
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KuZKy/)